# Don't allow inactive users to login in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I have done a system with users. Authenticate users is done by "php artisan make:auth", I have a column in `users` table called `activated`; when `activated = 0`, I don't want a user to log in. A little help please? Sorry if this clue has been boring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login only if user is active using Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015606/login-only-if-user-is-active-using-laravel)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i find out myself, i just add this to myLoginController.php

```
  protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $credentials['activated'] = 1;

    return $credentials;
}
```

Comment: Its Works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to handle this as either using the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait or manually part of your `AuthController` by checking the response from your login form and returning an appropriate response:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Class AuthController
 * @package Speechlink\Http\Controllers\Auth
 */
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     * @param AuthManager      $auth
     */
    public function __construct(AuthManager $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Deal with the login attempt (overrides the trait's postLogin method)
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return $this|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials)) {
            // We authenticated so continue
            return redirect('path/to/logged_in');
        } else {
            // We failed authentication so redirect somewhere else
            return redirect('path/to/disabled_user');
        }

    }
}
```