# Laravel how to prevent login of users based on extra flag on User model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I've implemented email verification schema for default Authentication mechanism of Laravel. However I'm stuck on how to prevent users with unverified emails from logging in.

I can test if user credentials are valid but then I can not retrieve user based on those credentials (`Auth::validate`).

Alternatively I could use `Auth::attempt` or `Auth::once` to log user, but then, they are logged in even though they may have unverified email.

I need either a way to query users by credentials, or a way to log user out in the same request. (bonus points if I can do it in `LoginController` `after` validation hook, thus returning proper error notice to user.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending#authentication

Comment: That docs look old. For 5.4 it returns 404.

Comment: It does, but extending functionality is what you are looking for. I also noticed that Laravel removed some articles that are still very interesting to read. Secondary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015606/login-only-if-user-is-active-using-laravel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in additional parameters to `Auth::attempt()`:

For example:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'verified' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users (under "Specifying Additional Conditions")