# Want to modify laravel default login to check user is verified or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have written code for email verification. I want to change my login controller behavior so that it will only allow verified users only.

I have status field in database that will store user is verified or not by storing 0/1. Now on login request I have to check  email, password, as well as status code is equal to 1. If verified, the user will be redirected to dashboard otherwise redirect to login with error message.

I have done all email verification things.

Please let me know what inputs you want.

Comment: make a check at login controller

Comment: can we modify on redirectIfAuthenticated middleware?

Comment: not in middleware, in your controller method, look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: It must be in login controller as @Sohel0415 said,check in your controller method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your LoginController

need to write following function there

```
protected function authenticated($request, $user){

    if(!$user->is_active){
        //logic here 

    }
}
```

In above example, `is_active` is your table attribute where you have user status...!!

Comment: @PrabaharanRajendran glad if it was really helpful___!!

Comment: @Pranav Mandlik You must accept it if it was helpful or if not let me know so, I can make it better

Comment: i have implemented like

Comment: protected function authenticated($request, $user){

        if(Auth::user()->status==0){
            //logic here 
            return redirect(route('login'));
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect(route('home'));
        }
    }

Comment: Better to use $user->status == 0 isted of above condition

Comment: i just have one question

Comment: in blade we write like   /@if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                /@endif

Comment: i want to set that $errors in controller how to set that?

Comment: sorry can you explain your question ?

Comment: In this solution, `is_active` is checked only after the user is already authenticated. So the user has to be logged out if inactive for this to work properly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [more elegant solution for this provided by BrokenBinary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31016210/3209381), which checks if the account is active or not while authentication, and returns a custom error message if account is inactive.

Comment: Thanks Sykez canot upvote now coz of limit reached will do it tomorow

Comment: @PranavMandlik Cool. Do look into that solution though :) Cheers