# Login a user only if his status is active in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am new to Laravel and have been fairly successful in implementing user authentication. Now to move on to the next step I must allow only users whose status in active to login. For that I have added a

```
status TINYINT
```

column in my mysql users table.

I found this in the Laravel Documentation:

> Specifying Additional Conditions
>
> If you wish, you may also add extra conditions to the authentication
>   query in addition to the user's e-mail and password. For example, we
>   may verify that user is marked as "active":
>
> ```
> if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
> // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
> }
> ```

Can someone please point out where I need to put this chunk. Am thoroughly confused and need some pointers.

Thanks

Comment: How do you currently authenticate users?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015606/login-only-if-user-is-active-using-laravel

Comment: @Jerodev I am using Laravel's built in auth with a couple of changes (like using username instead of email, I don't think they will be any consequence).

Comment: Like as said @MasivuyeCokile , There is so much solving method on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31015606/login-only-if-user-is-active-using-laravel

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have this on your LoginController:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{        
   return ['username' => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1];
}
```

Comment: `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::credentials() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in /Library/WebServer/Documents/transport/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 81`

Comment: My bad forgot to include `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: Accepted for the simplicity of the solution. Kudos and thanks

Answer (score 4):

You just take user status and check user status is true or false. You can take status using Auth::User()->status from auth session. Try this.

```
 if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password])){
                $userStatus = Auth::User()->status;
                if($userStatus=='1') {
                    return redirect()->intended(url('/dashboard'));
                }else{
                    Auth::logout();
                    Session::flush();
                    return redirect(url('login'))->withInput()->with('errorMsg','You are temporary blocked. please contact to admin');
                }
            }
            else {

                return redirect(url('login'))->withInput()->with('errorMsg','Incorrect username or password. Please try again.');
            }
```

Comment: Where? In Auth\LoginController?

Comment: app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

Comment: Hi Jasim, what is the  method name of your code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply put this code in your `App\Auth\LoginController` or elsewhere where you have your `LoginController`  located.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

with this code you are overriding default `authenticate` function

Comment: Am yet to try it out but your answer seems to make sense. My only concern is that I am redirecting the user to different dashboard base on a level field. For that I am using:

    `public function redirectTo() {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $level = $user->level;
        if($level == 0) {
            return '/home/super';
        } elseif($level == 1) {
            return '/home/accountant';
        } else {
        return '/home/branch';
    }`

How do I handle this redirection?

Comment: if You are redirecting it in different location you can place `protected $redirectTo = '/';` in your LoginController.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your LoginController:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{        
    return [$this->username() => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => $request->password, 'active' => 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below method in

> app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

and it would extend

> AuthenticatesUsers trait

validateLogin method. So basically, it would check for your active clause as well.

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => [
                'required',
                Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('active', 1);
                }),
            ],
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
    }
```

OR

Place your required code in **app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php**

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'active' => 1])) {
        // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override authenticated() method in your App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php like so:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
   if(!$user->active) {
       Auth::logout();
       abort(403);
   };
}
```

Do note it's quick but not very "Laravely" solution. Sloppy.